# interfacing OpenCV with php

Tags: php, opencv, interface, exec

I have an executable file developed using opencv library in cpp and c also. I want to execute it from my website hosted on localhost using a php script. 
The problem i'm facing is that, the executable code opens a window(kind of gui, opened using namedWindow) when called from terminal but it doesn't do that when called from the embedded php script. 
For execution i have tried exec, system but all these failed.

to be more clear : name of executable -> my_cv_gui, name of phpscript(page) ->abcd.php

```
@terminal if i type "./my_cv_gui" ... window opens.

@ terminal, if itype "php abcd.php" window opens

abcd.php is part of my website. In web browser if i open "http://...../abcd.php", window DOESNOT open. Although other things in the executable work perfectly.
```

My system configuration

OS : ubuntu 12.04 x64

XAMPP for Linux 1.7.7

Apache 2.2.21

PHP 5.3.8

Opencv 2.4.1

Any solutions??

The php code is as follows

```
<?php 

$output=shell_exec("gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-     raw-yuv,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1' ! ffenc_flv ! flvmux streamable=true ! queue ! filesink location=/home/dev/my.avi > /dev/null &");

var_dump($output); 
?>
```

Comment: Can you put the PHP code that you are using into the question?

Comment: Try using `$output=system("...");`.

Comment: What you want is impossible. You can't open an opencv window over an http connection, nor any window for that matter. If you simply want to execute the program, you need to give apache access to xorg because running it in a non-xorg environment will cause the program to fail

Comment: @Robin : I think your suggestion might work for me... And yes what i want to do is invoke a gui program on server only using this.

Comment: @Robin : I want to know how can i give apache access to the xorg... please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you should always remember when you are working with apache.

1. File/Folder Permission. Using which the apache is running.
2. MIME type should be added to apache to run any kind of multimedia components. Like here it's flv. Then try running the php code and try fixing it. I will check in my server if that works for me. Will update you.

Biswadip.